# c++ How to pass a name to the constructor of base class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, arguments, radix

I have two classes and I want every object of *subclass* to have a name, which is passed as an argument to the constructor of *superclass*. How do I do this?

```
class base
{
   public:
     base(const char * name) {name = name;}
     const char * getName() {return name;};
   private:
     const char * name;
};
class derived : public base
{
   public:
     derived(const char * name) : base(name) {}
};
```

However,

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    derived d("test");
    std::cout << d.getName();
}
```

produces gibberish as the the console output.

Comment: in this case people figured it out without the error message, but in general on SO just saying "produces Gibberish", instead of copy-pasting the errors, is bad form

Comment: @ChrisBeck In this case there is no error message for the OP to report.  There may have been a warning depending on his toolchain and settings, but this is a program with undefined behavior that in most cases will output random memory and then terminate without error.

Comment: @Chrisbeck Yes I didn't get any error message or warning, just some random characters on the console.

Comment: Ok but then its a lot more specific to say that instead of "produces gibberish". Not that you need to describe the gibberish, but is it runtime gibberish or compile-time gibberish?

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I'll do that next time right away  and edit the post. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to choose better name for parameter `name`:

```
base(const char * p_name) {name = p_name;}
```

in you code you are just assigning name to itself.

Other possible solutions:

```
base(const char * name) : name(name) {} // preferred one
base(const char * name) {base::name = name;}
base(const char * name) {this->name = name;}
```

Comment: note that this would not be a problem if OP had used the constructors initializer list instead of the constructor body.

Comment: The other option is to use a distinct member variable name. Or a convention, how member variable names should be built. Prefixing the parameter name might lead to semantical confusion (e.g. in this specific case `p` stands for pointer or _parameter_?).

Comment: `p` would be for parameter

Comment: Note:  This copies pointers and not content.  The OP should use `std::string` or make a copy of the character array (including dynamically allocating a copy and using `strcpy`).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, bullocks. If the class contract specifies that pointer to the char should outlive the class (as will be the case with string literal) doing extra memory allocation and than all the jumps with every assignment and copy construction is just insane.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you're assigning `name` to itself. So the member variable `const char * name` won't have the correct value. Since this is C++ though you should really use `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
class base
{
   public:
     base(std::string name) {m_name = name;}
     std::string getName() {return m_name;};
   private:
     std::string m_name;
};
class derived : public base
{
   public:
     derived(std::string name) : base(name) {}
};
```

Comment: This suffers from a different problem. The member variable gets default constructed. It does not use the input argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the way you use `name` in the body of the constructor, where it is local parameter. To fix the code, either use initialization lists or refer to member name through `this`.

Example 1 (member list, preferred!):

```
base(const char * name) : name(name) {}
```

Example 2 (use `this`, not preferred):

```
base(const char * name) : { this->name = name; }
```

Answer (score 1):

- `name` is used twice in the constructor, you could change the member to `name_` for example:

  ```
  class base
  {
     public:
       base(const char * name) {name_ = name;}
       const char * getName() {return name_;};
     private:
       const char * name_;
  };
  ```

  or use a initialization list:

  ```
   base(const char * name) : name(name) {}
  ```

  if you want to keep the same name for the parameter as well as for the member variable.
- In C++, you can use `std::string` instead of a `char*` for the name.
- In `class base`, no memory is allocated for `name` (in this case it would be better to copy the data with `strcpy()` instead of keeping a pointer to a constant parameter).

Comment: What's the reason for those dreaded underscores **after** the member name?

Comment: @SergeyA - It's one option to name the members. See for example: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Class_Format

Comment: Danny, I know many stupid guidelines have it. (google guideline is uber stupid, btw). Why do **you** follow it?

Comment: @SergeyA - Oh, buy I'm not following it (it was just the easiest way to change the names in this case). Actually, I'm somewhat stuck to the [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) in MFC most of the time (hard to mix both). That would be like: m_strName - you like that better? :)

Comment: Me? I like name. Plain and simple, and conveys all the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with ambiguous use of the `name` symbol.

The obvious answer is:

**Make the symbols of parameter and member variable unambiguous.**

---

Your code can be fixed like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
   public:
     base(const char * name) {name_ = name;}
     const char * getName() {return name_;};
   private:
     const char * name_; // <<< Just make the member variable unambiguous.
};
class derived : public base
{
   public:
     derived(const char * name) : base(name) {}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    derived d("test");
    std::cout << d.getName() << std::endl;
}
```

See the [working demo](http://ideone.com/xEbci5) please.

Comment: And you too :) Why a sore to the eye in the form of `name_`?

Comment: @SergeyA Because prefixed `_` is reserved.

Comment: @SergeyA And of course is shorter than providing `this->` and is more convenient to read when used in the member initializer list.

Comment: @SergeyA - maybe it's becoming a standard :) -- m_Name would be allowed too though.

Comment: @Danny_ds I don't believe it's becoming standard. It's just one of my preferred naming patterns :-) .... And `m_name` needs one more character and looks so ugly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Well, it's standard in [the Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Class_Format)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - _"Data members of classes (but not structs) additionally have trailing underscores."_ - https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Variable_Names

Comment: @Danny_ds Well, Google is big, but they are (hopefully) not running the world on themselves.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, who told you so (prefixed _ is reserved)? prefix _ is perfectly fine for class members. But even that aside, why do you even need the prefix or postfix?

Comment: Google standard is **uber** stupid in many ways, and here as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
base(const char * name) {name = name;}
```

is not doing what you are expecting. In the function, the argument `name` shadows the member variable `name`. Hence, the member variable never gets initialized.

You can use:

```
base(const char * name) : name(name) {}
```

or better

```
base(const char * nameIn) : name(nameIn) {}
```

Suggestion for further improvement:

Use a `std::string` for the member variable. Then your class doesn't have to deal with problems that might arise if the pointer becomes a dangling pointer after the constructor is called.

```
class base
{
   public:
     base(const char * nameIn) : name(nameIn) {}
     std::string const& getName() {return name;} const;
   private:
     std::string name;
};
```